# Как vosk подключить к rust?

Tags: rust, vosk

Хотел (и хочу) подключить библиотеку "vosk"(распознавание речи) к языку rust. Вроде делаю всё как по документации, а всё равно получаю ошибку.

Код:

```
use vosk;
use vosk::Model;
use vosk::Recognizer;

fn main() {
    let samples = vec![100, -2, 700, 30, 4, 5];
    let model_path = "/vosk-ua-model-v3-small";

    let model = Model::new(model_path).unwrap();
    let mut recognizer = Recognizer::new(&model, 16000.0).unwrap();

    recognizer.set_max_alternatives(10);
    recognizer.set_words(true);
    recognizer.set_partial_words(true);

    for sample in samples.chunks(100) {
        recognizer.accept_waveform(sample);
        println!("{:#?}", recognizer.partial_result());
    }

    println!("{:#?}", recognizer.final_result().multiple().unwrap());
}
```

Ошибка1:

```
note: "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "C:\\Users\\marks\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustcGCxLSx\\symbols.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.1bk80tifjfpyrbix.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.1nz6xjdxdk2lkoqi.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.24v6h8wqa0l75kvx.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.2ifsq8lhip4h89es.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.2powp9hyz9okp92k.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.30hp4m1kxx23l1hc.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.37k4agujiz0q7tku.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.3bx3x6lbpa862sga.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.3kj3dmi3nqx1l531.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.3n5zab1ajgheaf9g.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.3t03hzrxbc076rhl.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.3v2q5f04s00jn84n.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.48cpnfy7t9j2jed.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.4jf8mxzdt0lg2za4.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.4n9itpmazdxcfsme.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.4raacb67kllfv56w.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.4x6or003ka16wuk8.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.54vpen2io2bhj2po.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.56rkx7teu386rkcw.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.5b1ozqjcz85dh1ps.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.5gphvutcyl8im9dt.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.5x8evmnssg94dvw.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.7teu7yql3mg8wax.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.iwmqkotuy4nwj0f.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.3m9x46t5elh6dual.rcgu.o" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\libvosk-db6e4f457c366d41.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\libserde_json-e53e24780b6435f8.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\libryu-480b19f363246e7c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\libitoa-574961d0d6185507.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\libserde-0e37dfe39c2dc491.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\libvosk_sys-9150add6b5c6d36e.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd-391022a4250a8b9a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-3069c74fd845ecc2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_demangle-cae8325b8f11cb55.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd_detect-6ecbb4a24be3ec33.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libhashbrown-7cef55517a70b408.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libminiz_oxide-d1e72b1788c7e8f6.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libadler-65d80753bac4b1a6.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-932a6231bea08890.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libunwind-04ed514427316340.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcfg_if-9b75e26b1d0a074f.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liblibc-95c2795d82b7b742.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liballoc-1bf02ac2d8cdb80a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-117dfa1fe8688bcf.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcore-9ac5797c0b4842d0.rlib" "C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-ad271357e078d260.rlib" "libvosk.lib" "kernel32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "userenv.lib" "kernel32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "bcrypt.lib" "ntdll.lib" "msvcrt.lib" "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib" "/NXCOMPAT" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "/OUT:C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\rusttest\\app\\target\\debug\\deps\\app.exe" "/OPT:REF,NOICF" "/DEBUG" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\intrinsic.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\liballoc.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libcore.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\marks\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libstd.natvis"
```

Ошибка2:

```
note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libvosk.lib'
```

Я прекрастно понимаю что "Ошибка1" = не установлены файлы, НО файлы C++ с инсталлера 2022 и 2019 годов Visual Studio у меня установлены.

Ошибка2 - не находит файл "libvosk.lib", но как его подключить я без понятия. Я знаю что есть [Build Scripts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html), но как его использовать не понимаю.

Скрин папки:
[image]

vosk через комманду "cargo add vosk" я установил.

На таких сайтах я впервые, по этому, если есть вопросы или недопонимания - пишите.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://crates.io/crates/vosk